# Erase ellipse from figure?

Tags: matplotlib, ellipse

I'm new at python and new at graphics!!
the thing is that I'm implementing an EKF map-based localization and I want to plot the uncertenty ellipse. For that I do, each time I want to update the figure with all the values I call a function call animate, which inside has this:

```
ellipse = matplotlib.patches.Arc([x_B_1[0,0],x_B_1[0,1]],P_B_1[0,0],P_B_1[1,1],x_B_1[0,2]*180/pi,color='green', linewidth='0.5')
ax.add_patch(ellipse)
```

And some other stuff

The thing is that by doing this all the ellipses saty in the figure and I get a mess (I can not post a picture of the figure because it's my first post and the forum does not allow me to do it), I want just the last ellipse.

How can I do it?

---

I can not do that because everything in the figure is lost, I just want to erase the ellipse not the rest of the things that I have on that figure, maybe it's not possible... Is there any option of updating the ellipse parameters so instead of drawing a new one I just update the one already drawn??

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that you have to clear the figure before you plot something else. Try with the `clf()` command of matplotlib

Comment: How do I use the `clf` method with a list of ellipses?

Answer (score 4):

`ellipse.remove()` should do what you want

Answer (score 0):

I see. You than want to, as you said, update the figure plot using `set_data`. Have a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7187504/set-data-and-autoscale-view-matplotlib) for how to use it.