# Recenter plot after set_xdata and set_ydata

Tags: python, matplotlib

I can use the `set_xdata` and `set_ydata` functions to update an existing matplotlib plot. But after updating I want to recenter the plot so that all the points fall into the "view" of the plot.

In the below example, the y data keeps getting bigger but the zoom level of the plot remains same so the data points quickly get out of the scope.

```py
import time

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
y = np.sin(x)

plt.ion()

figure, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 8))
(line1,) = ax.plot(x, y)

plt.xlabel("X-axis")
plt.ylabel("Y-axis")

for i in range(1000):
    new_y = np.sin(x - 0.5 * i) * i
    line1.set_xdata(x)
    line1.set_ydata(new_y)
    figure.canvas.draw()
    figure.canvas.flush_events()
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Automatically Rescale ylim and xlim in Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984085/automatically-rescale-ylim-and-xlim-in-matplotlib)

Comment: Thanks, yes it did!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `ax.relim()` and `ax.autoscale()` fixes the issue

```py
import time

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
y = np.sin(x)

plt.ion()

ax: plt.Axes
figure, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 8))
(line1,) = ax.plot(x, y)
ax.autoscale(True)

plt.xlabel("X-axis")
plt.ylabel("Y-axis")

for i in range(1000):
    new_y = np.sin(x - 0.5 * i) * i
    line1.set_xdata(x)
    line1.set_ydata(new_y)
    
    # Rescale axes limits
    ax.relim()
    ax.autoscale()

    figure.canvas.draw()
    figure.canvas.flush_events()
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Answer (score 0):

`np.sin(x - 0.5 * i)` has multiplied by `i`, which can be 1000. One alternative is to make the y-axis have a limit greater than 1000. So, you can include `plt.ylim([-1100,1100])`:

```
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
y = np.sin(x)

plt.ion()

figure, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 8))
(line1,) = ax.plot(x, y)

plt.xlabel("X-axis")
plt.ylabel("Y-axis")
plt.ylim([-1100,1100])

for i in range(1000):
    new_y = np.sin(x - 0.5 * i) * i
    line1.set_xdata(x)
    line1.set_ydata(new_y)
    figure.canvas.draw()
    figure.canvas.flush_events()
    time.sleep(0.1)
```