# autoscaling not working on drawing arrow

Tags: python, matplotlib

Trying to draw a simple arrow in Matplotlib using the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.arrow(1, 1, 1, 1)
plt.show()
```

which results in an empty plot.

If the arrow specifications are changed to `ax.arrow(0, 0, 1, 1)` then I do see an arrow in the final plot. So I suspected that it is probably an issue with the scaling of the axes, so I modified the code based on recommendations in [Matplotlib autoscale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3214576/matplotlib-autoscale?rq=1) to the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.arrow(1, 1, 1, 1)
ax.relim()
ax.autoscale_view()
plt.show()
```

which also does not work.

I found that manually setting the limits as in the following works

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.arrow(1, 1, 1, 1)
ax.set_xlim(0, 5)
ax.set_ylim(0, 5)
plt.show()
```

Strange also was my discovery that `ax.set_xlim()` alone or `ax.set_ylim()` alone do not work I have to set both the limits for the arrow to become visible.

Questions:

- Does `ax.arrow` require special handling?
- Am I missing some commands apart from `ax.relim()` and `ax.autoscale_view()`?
- Why do I have to set both `xlim` and `ylim`?

Versions:

- Python: 3.5.1
- Matplotlib: 1.5.1
- Linux: 64 bit Archlinux

Comment: Looks like a bug or unspecified behavior to me. Adding no arrow gives the same x/y-scales when autoscaling. Your arrow starts at 1,1 and moves 1 up and 1 right, therefore you need to both xlim and ylim. If you set only xlim to 0,5 your window will x:0,5 and y:0,1 and the arrow will be still outside your frame.

Comment: @Ashafix thanks, your explanation as to why both `xlim` and `ylim` are needed makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

The problem persists on Windows 10 and Ubuntu 14 with the latest version of matplotlib and Python 3.4/3.5. A simple workaround is to create a helper function `arrow_` which creates two invisible points at the beginning and end of the arrow.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

def arrow_(ax, plt, x, y, dx, dy, **kwargs):
    ax.arrow(x, y, dx, dy, **kwargs)
    plt.plot([x, x + dx + 0.1], [y, y + dx + 0.1], alpha=0)

arrow_(ax, plt, 1, 1, 1, 1)
ax.relim()
#plt.plot([1.8], [1.5], 'ro')
ax.autoscale_view()
plt.show()
```

- The commented line is just to demonstrate that the invisible dots don't interfere with the rest of the graph.
- The added value of 0.1 is just to compensate for the arrow head.

Comment: Coming to this answer after a few years. I don't think this bug has been resolved? I was trying to plot an arrow doing this `ax.arrow(10,50,12,3)` and the figure shows nothing and limits to only 1.0 and 1.0 on both axes.

Comment: yeah I have the same issue